# Rails model instance with dynamic attribute value based on relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model

My AdminUser creates a survey and the questions that go along with it.  A different User then takes the survey.  A survey will be taken by multiple Users.  Some of the questions in the survey, will need to include an attribute of that User (example: name).  So the AdminUser would create a question like "What did USER eat?" but the User who takes the survey will see "What did Jane eat?".

Currently, I have a Survey model and a Question model.  I would like the questions in the survey to include the user's name that is taking the survey.  As an example, if the question is "What do you eat?" I would like it to say "What does Jan eat?"

To temporarily accomplish this I created a method on my Survey model that creates new Questions each time a new survey is created.  This is clogging up my database with ultimately the same questions with just 1 word difference.  It also makes it more difficult to link different users' answers to the same question since each question instance is unique.

Here is my current Survey model

**survey.rb**

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :surveyable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy


  def self.generate_for_user(survey_user)
      new_survey = Survey.new
      new_survey.surveyable_id = survey_user.id
      new_survey.surveyable_type = "User"
      new_survey.user = client
      new_survey.save
      Question.new(position: 1, tier: 1, content: "When did you first become aware of #{survey_user.first_name}'s needs?", question_type: "Response", survey_group: "User", survey_group_question_id: 1, choices: "", survey_id: new_survey.id).save

      Question.new(position: 2, tier: 1, content: "What foods does #{survey_user.first_name} regularly need to avoid?", question_type: "Response", survey_group: "User", survey_group_question_id: 2, choices: "", survey_id: new_survey.id).save

     ... and so on ...

end
```

Here is my current Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

As you can see, I really dont think I went about this the right way.

How can I create Questions that can have a dynamic attribute that is based on one of its relationships?  Is that possible?

Do I need the attribute to be static with a placeholder and then call a method on the question that inserts the dynamic name into the placeholder when its called?

I would like to be able to call

```
Question.new(content: "What does #{survey_user_name} eat?")
Question.new(content: "What does #{survey_user_name} wear?")
```

And I want the #{name} to be replaced with the survey owner.  So the same question can be applied to many different surveys and still use the specific survey owners name.

Comment: So, the problem is that you don't want to save Questions into DB?

Comment: I want hte questions to save to the database, I want the survey to map to many questions and a question to map to many surveys....but I want the question attribute/column value called :content to be a string that is different depending on who the survey is mapped to.

Comment: did you try meta programming?

Comment: @sadaf2605 I did not and am not sure how to go about doing that in this scenario (and am not very familiar with it in general)

Comment: My thought was to store the question in the database with some strange token where you want the user's info to go and then just regex that out when it comes time to show the question. You'd only have one row in your DB for each general question, so you don't need to store each user's custom question.

Comment: @nicholas79171 that sounds like how I wouuld like to do it.  How would you go about setting that up (minus the details of the regex which I can work through)

Comment: @MicFin it's a really rough idea and not sure if it'll work, but check out the answer I'm about to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rename the `content` column to `content_raw`

Then define a method in `question` model, like

```
def content(maybe_some_params)
  content_raw.gsub(.....)
end
```

In this case, you can reuse the same question record if `content_raw` is the same

Comment: So if I was to create a new instance of a Question that has new content, would I need to create a new method for each one?

Comment: not quite.  I updated my question.  Having trouble expressing the result i need

Comment: I guess you want to allow users to input their questions, then replace part of the question with user's info, right? If so, check my updated ans

Comment: exactly!  I will add that to my question.  An AdminUser creates a survey and the questions and some of those questions will need a placeholder in them (or something) for the name of the User that takes the survey.

Comment: Then, use my approach. Let AdminUser create questions. gsub content_raw with current_user.name

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ':after_create' hook. It is going to create following Questions, every time a survey will be created and when there is survey, you will have the owner of the survey.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :create_random_question
   def create_random_question:
Question.new(position: 1, tier: 1, content: "When did you first become aware of #{user.first_name}'s needs?", question_type: "Response", survey_group: "User", survey_group_question_id: 1, choices: "", survey_id: new_survey.id).save
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some *really* rough code that might help you have one question "template" and just sub in that user's data when it comes to render the form.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey

  def self.generate_questions(survey_id)
    Question.new(content: "When did you first become aware of USER_FIRST_NAME's needs?", survey_id: survey_id)
    Question.new(content: "What food does USER_FIRST_NAME regularly need to avoid?")
  end

end

class SurveysController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @questions = Questions.where(survey_id: 4)
    survey_user = User.find(user_id)
    @questions.each do |q|
      # Use a switch to determine which string to look for and what to sub it with
      case q.id
      when 1 
        q.content = q.content.gsub(.....)
      when 2
        q.content = q.content.gsub(.....)
      when 3
        q.content = q.content.gsub(.....)
      when 4
        q.content = q.content.gsub(.....)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I'm not positive how your models are set up or what attributes you have, but it's definitely something to go on.